# What successful/well known companies have a VP UX?

Tags: research, career-development

I want to research companies who value UX so much  that they have their own executive arm within the company.

I've found these companies so far:

- Wells Fargo
- Yahoo
- Intuit
- Google
- TiVo
- Palm
- Ebay
- SAP

I also wonder if anyone working for these companies can speak to UX's role within the organization.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out LinkedIn was the most valuable tool for researching. You can see the over 500 companies or just read about eh 4 which were HUGE successful co's with a vp ux here: http://userexperienceexperience.blogspot.com/2009/10/companies-with-vp-of-ux.html

I also found a lot of director-level UX people (like facebook) I may do another post about just directors.